# Плавное перемещение карты яндекс по клику

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Как можно реализовать плавное перемещение карты для каждого элемента отдельно? Т.е. задаю какой-то переключатель и он привязывается к одной точке. И эти переключатели могли находится в любом месте экрана.
На сайте Яндекса есть пример для списка: http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/examples/mappanto.html

```html
<ul id="mapMenu"></ul>
<div id="YMapsID" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>
```

```js
var destinations = {
  'Москва': new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.609218, 55.753559),
  'Санкт-Петербург': new YMaps.GeoPoint(30.313497, 59.938531),
  'Екатеринбург': new YMaps.GeoPoint(60.617435, 56.829748),
  'Одесса': new YMaps.GeoPoint(30.7058, 46.466444)
};

// Устанавливает центр карты на первом городе из списка
map.setCenter(destinations['Москва'], 10);

var menuContainer = YMaps.jQuery('#mapMenu');

// Создает список городов
for (var item in destinations) {
  // Использует замыкание, чтобы работать с конкретным свойством объекта
  (function(title, geoPoint) {
    // Создает ссылку, обернутую в тег <p> для лучшей читаемости
    YMaps.jQuery("<li><a href=\"#\">" + item + "</'a></li>")
      .find('a')
      // По щелчку на ссылке создает обработчик
      .bind('click', function() {

        // Подчеркивает все ссылки
        menuContainer.find('a').css('text-decoration', 'underline');

        // Кроме той, что была выбрана пользователем
        YMaps.jQuery(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');

        // Перемещает карту
        map.panTo(geoPoint, {
          flying: 1
        });
        return false;
      })
      .end()

      // Записывает созданный элемент списка в список
      .appendTo(menuContainer);
  })(item, destinations[item])
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понимаю, ведь у вас все в примере есть.
Протренеровался с вашим примером до пол второго, зато теперь буду знать как с ними на фидлере работать - http://jsfiddle.net/vdann/YDg62/14/.
Вот здесь правда удобней проверять - http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/

Comment: Спасибо огромное!
Еще такой вопросик. Как можно сделать, что бы все ссылки были с одним названием, к примеру: "посмотреть на карте", но переключали каждая свой город?

Comment: Как это все привязать к карте из конструктора с id?)

Comment: в html - ... <div id="map" ...

в js -  ... myMap = new ymaps.Map('map' ...

Comment: Напомнило мне мультик - "A семь шапок можешь?"

 http://jsfiddle.net/vdann/YDg62/19/

Comment: Все работает. А возможно еще увеличение(приближение) по клику на метку с зум 5 на 14???