# Переключение адресов на яндекс карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Нашел такой [пример кода](http://jsfiddle.net/vdann/YDg62/19/) из комментариев к вопросу - [Плавное перемещение карты яндекс по клику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229452/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83)

Подставил свои значения в `data-goto = "Киев"` и все перестало работать.

Вопрос как можно настроить переключение карты по клику на ссылку (адрес через `data-goto`) и как разместить кастомный маркер на карте с этим самым адресом?

Подозреваю что вывод маркера можно сделать как-то так

```
myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark(destinations['Киев'], {
                balloonContent: ...
```

Но что-то с `destinations[data-goto]` что-то никак не свяжу.

```js
 //Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
  ymaps.ready(init);

  function init() {
      var result = document.getElementById('result'), // для отладки

          // в этой версии координаты просто элементы массива (и они поменяны местами)
          destinations = {
              'Москва': [55.753559, 37.609218],
              'Санкт-Петербург': [59.938531, 30.313497],
              'Екатеринбург': [56.829748, 60.617435],
              'Одесса': [46.466444, 30.7058]
          },

          // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
          // заданным id ("map").
          myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
              // При инициализации карты обязательно нужно указать
              // её центр и коэффициент масштабирования.
              center: destinations['Москва'], // Москва
              zoom: 10
          });

      // все ок
      result.textContent = 'map init';

      // куда скакать
      function clickGoto() {

          // город
          var pos = this.getAttribute('data-goto'); // или this.getAttribute('title')
          result.textContent = pos;

          // переходим по координатам
          myMap.panTo(destinations[pos], {
              flying: 1
          });

          return false;
      }

      // навешиваем обработчики
      var col = document.getElementsByClassName('goto');
      for (var i = 0, n = col.length; i < n; ++i) {
          col[i].onclick = clickGoto;
          result.textContent = result.textContent + ' ' + i;
      }
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <div id="map" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>

 <a href=\"#\" class="goto" data-goto="Москва" title="Москва">Перейти</a><br>
 <a href=\"#\" class="goto" data-goto="Киев" title="Киев">Перейти</a><br>
 <a href=\"#\" class="goto" data-goto="Екатеринбург" title="Екатеринбург">Перейти</a><br>
 <a href=\"#\" class="goto" data-goto="Одесса" title="Одесса">Перейти</a>

 <div id="result"></div>
```

Так вообще не работает не кастомный значок не клик:

```js
//Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
  ymaps.ready(init);

  function init() {

         // в этой версии координаты просто элементы массива (и они поменяны местами)
         destinations = {
             'Москва': [55.753559, 37.609218],
             'Санкт-Петербург': [59.938531, 30.313497],
             'Екатеринбург': [56.829748, 60.617435],
             'Одесса': [46.466444, 30.7058]
         },

         // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
         // заданным id ("map").
         myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
             center: destinations['Москва'], 
             zoom: 10,
             controls: []
         });


      // куда скакать
      function clickGoto() {

          // город
          var pos = this.getAttribute('data-goto'); // или this.getAttribute('title')
          result.textContent = pos;

          // переходим по координатам
          myMap.panTo(destinations[pos], {
              flying: 1
          });

          return false;
      }

      // навешиваем обработчики
      var col = document.getElementsByClassName('goto');
      for (var i = 0, n = col.length; i < n; ++i) {
          col[i].onclick = clickGoto;
          result.textContent = result.textContent + ' ' + i;
      }



      var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(destinations['Москва'], {
          
      }, {
          iconImageHref: 'map-icon.png',
          iconImageSize: [79, 96],
          iconImageOffset: [0, -50],
      });

      /* Добавляем */
      myMap.geoObjects
          .add(myPlacemark);


      
  }
```

```html
 <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <div id="map" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>

 <a href=\"#\" class="goto" data-goto="Москва" title="Москва">Перейти</a><br>
 <a href=\"#\" class="goto" data-goto="Киев" title="Киев">Перейти</a><br>
 <a href=\"#\" class="goto" data-goto="Екатеринбург" title="Екатеринбург">Перейти</a><br>
 <a href=\"#\" class="goto" data-goto="Одесса" title="Одесса">Перейти</a>

 <div id="result"></div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста в решении проблемы!!!

Заранее не известны все адреса, редактироваться будут только через data атрибут а не через скрипт, поэтому прописывать вручную все адреса в `destinations` нет смысла.

Вообщем есть ссылки с адресами типа строки, карта. Как осуществить отображение нужного адреса на карте по клику на ссылку с этим самым адресом?

Comment: Чтобы работало `destinations['Киев']` нужно, как минимум, чтобы этот `destinations['Киев']` существовал.

Comment: @br3t, заранее не известны все адреса, редактироваться будут только через data атрибут а не через скрипт.

Comment: Тогда вам надо будет в ссылки прописывать и координаты

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Необходимо добавить Киев с массив `destination`, чтобы иметь возможность переходить на него
2. В API 2.0 несколько другой способ добавления маркеров
3. Привести в порядок атрибуты `href` для ссылок не помешает.

Минимально модифицировав ваш код, получилось так:

```js
//Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

  var result = document.getElementById('result'),
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [55.753559, 37.609218], // Москва
      zoom: 12
    });

  // все ок
  result.textContent = 'map init';

  // куда скакать
  function clickGoto() {

    // город
    var city = this.getAttribute('data-goto'); // или this.getAttribute('title')
    result.textContent = city;

    // получение координат по адресу - асинхронная функция
    var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(city);
    myGeocoder.then(
      function(res) {
        coords = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();

        // переходим по координатам
        myMap.panTo(coords, {
          flying: 1
        });
        // добавляем маркер
        var placeMark = new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
          balloonContent: city
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(placeMark);
      },
      function(err) {
        alert('Ошибка');
      }
    );
    return false;
  }

  // навешиваем обработчики
  var col = document.getElementsByClassName('goto');
  for (var i = 0, n = col.length; i < n; ++i) {
    col[i].onclick = clickGoto;
    result.textContent = result.textContent + ' ' + i;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>

<a href="#" class="goto" data-goto="Россия, Москва, Красная площадь, 1" title="Москва">Россия, Москва, Красная площадь, 1</a><br>
<a href="#" class="goto" data-goto="Украина, Киев, улица Крещатик, 1/2" title="Киев">Украина, Киев, улица Крещатик, 1/2</a><br>
<a href="#" class="goto" data-goto="Россия, Свердловская область, Екатеринбург, проспект Ленина, 1" title="Екатеринбург">Россия, Свердловская область, Екатеринбург, проспект Ленина, 1</a><br>
<a href="#" class="goto" data-goto="Украина, Одесса, Приморский бульвар, 1" title="Одесса">Украина, Одесса, Приморский бульвар, 1</a>

<div id="result"></div>
```

В идеале - хранить инфо о том, какие маркеры уже созданы, чтобы не создавать их снова, но вроде бы yandex их не дублирует.

Comment: "Вообщем есть ссылки с адресами типа строки, карта. Как осуществить отображение нужного адреса на карте по клику на ссылку с этим самым адресом?"

Comment: Адреса без координат?

Comment: @hug, исправил сниппет на адреса без координат.

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно. Награда через 20 часов, 100 балов ваши!

Comment: А как сделать в модальном окне boostrap4?

Comment: @Never3D, в чем именно проблема? Помещаете код карты в модальное окно, при необходимости - по клику по ссылке окно показываете