# Перестановка балуна и выделения на яндекс карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Использовал пример [из этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662204/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5) для перемещения по карте с помощью ссылок. 
Теперь вопрос таков - как можно реализовать переключение балуна и выделения области при переходе по ссылкам, чтобы при переходе к области отображались только ее балун (который, если не ошибаюсь, может быть открыт только в единственном экземпляре) и выделенная область?

Answer (score 1):

На карте, действительно, может быть открыт только один балун. Поэтому достаточно после установки метки открывать её балун следующим методом:

```
placeMark.balloon.open();
```

Про выделенную область непонятно, поясните, пожалуйста. Если имеется в виду возможность подсветить границы региона, города или улицу как на Яндекс.Картах, то такой возможности в публичном API Карт нет.

P.S. лучше использовать актуальную версию API 2.1, потому что для 2.0 уже не появляются новые фичи и не исправляются ошибки совместимости с современными браузерами. Исправила на версию 2.1 в Вашем примере.

```js
//Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

  var result = document.getElementById('result'),
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [55.753559, 37.609218], // Москва
      zoom: 12
    });

  // все ок
  result.textContent = 'map init';

  // куда скакать
  function clickGoto() {

    // город
    var city = this.getAttribute('data-goto'); // или this.getAttribute('title')
    result.textContent = city;

    // получение координат по адресу - асинхронная функция
    var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(city);
    myGeocoder.then(
      function(res) {
        coords = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();

        // переходим по координатам
        myMap.panTo(coords, {
          flying: 1
        });
        // добавляем маркер
        var placeMark = new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
          balloonContent: city
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(placeMark);
        placeMark.balloon.open();
      },
      function(err) {
        alert('Ошибка');
      }
    );
    return false;
  }

  // навешиваем обработчики
  var col = document.getElementsByClassName('goto');
  for (var i = 0, n = col.length; i < n; ++i) {
    col[i].onclick = clickGoto;
    result.textContent = result.textContent + ' ' + i;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>

<a href="#" class="goto" data-goto="Россия, Москва, Красная площадь, 1" title="Москва">Россия, Москва, Красная площадь, 1</a><br>
<a href="#" class="goto" data-goto="Украина, Киев, улица Крещатик, 1/2" title="Киев">Украина, Киев, улица Крещатик, 1/2</a><br>
<a href="#" class="goto" data-goto="Россия, Свердловская область, Екатеринбург, проспект Ленина, 1" title="Екатеринбург">Россия, Свердловская область, Екатеринбург, проспект Ленина, 1</a><br>
<a href="#" class="goto" data-goto="Украина, Одесса, Приморский бульвар, 1" title="Одесса">Украина, Одесса, Приморский бульвар, 1</a>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Не совсем точно выразился - не выделение границы региона, а выделение области с помощью полигона, сейчас на карте только один статичный через var myPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon.

Спасибо за правку под 2.1)

Comment: Сейчас у меня на карте задается балун через 

myMap.balloon.open(myMap.getCenter(), {
                contentBody:

работая без метки

Comment: Про балун - тут исключительно, как вам удобнее. можно и без метки.
Про полигон - можно рисовать его до открытия балуна или менять его геометрию, в зависимости от выбранного города. Если с этим возникают сложности, лучше задать новый вопрос с полным кодом.